# Convert cms page content to html interpretation Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

in my **root.phtml**, I can call for cms page content with :

```
<?php echo $layoutContent; ?>
```

but I wanted to use `$cmsPage->getContent()` instead :

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
echo $cmsPage->getContent();
?>
```

I get this for result which is correct but not converting to html interpretation :

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::cms/home.phtml"}}
```

Do you know if I could get it work ? **( `toHtml()` function return error )**

Thanks

Comment: https://bit.ly/2ofZIHT refers link.

Answer (score 0):

Find an answer

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
$content = $cmsPage->getContent();
$filterManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
echo $filterManager;
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Ravindra/slider/Block/slider.php

```
<?php
namespace Ravindra\slider\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class slider extends Template
{

    protected $filterProvider;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }
    public function getCmsFilterContent($content)
    {
        $filterManager = $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);

        return $filterManager;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Ravindra/Slider/view/frontend/templates/slider.phtml

```
<div class="slide_content">
    <?php echo $block->getCmsFilterContent($_slider['content']); ?>
</div>
```